# quick multi-language submit in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api, google-play-console

when I want to submit a new android app, I must enter every single language description, short description and title.

I want to do this very quickly by preparing the translation first then put them at one in the Android developer submitting console.

How can I put my own translation in Google Play Developer account at once? Is there a tool that help me do this quickly without translating every single language and past it down?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quick with buying the translations on the console, but I think that is not what you want.

I think there is no other way to add translations without going the normal way.

Comment: Ok thank you, but I heart about some scripts that do the translation quickly, I don't know if the submission is integrated too or not.